# How to add geckodriver to android to run selenium code in QPython

Tags: python, android, selenium, webdriver, geckodriver

i have some testing code which i wrote in selenium and usually run on Ubuntu.
I want to be able to run these testing on my android tablet with Qpython app.
All is ok but i struggle with installation of Gecko driver.
It says that it supports android but i cant see any version for android here:
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.28.0

can anyone help me with some tips  how to configure it at android?
(alternativelly chrome webdriver would do the job too,  but not sure how  to install it neither);

Thanx.

Comment: I think you would need Selendroid for this... http://selendroid.io/  But this is for testing apps.  Depending on what you are trying to do you might consider using this droid port of HTMLUnit:  https://github.com/null-dev/HtmlUnit-Android  (haven't used it myself, but I'm interested in hearing about your results if you do)

Comment: yeah, I need to test online website, not an android application. 
I just wanna use the standard selenium / python code; It works on linux, i just cant find way to install any webdriver in android ;-(